# Webpack file-loader the difference between the html templates and css to extract the images url

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I wish to have in my CSS files, the image url like this: `../img/`,
and in html tempates like this: `img/`,

But currently with the code below, i can not distinguish between webpack templates and css :

```
 {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/sass'),
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',      
    publicPath: '../img/',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          minimize: true,
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          plugins: (loader) => [
            require('autoprefixer')({
              browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 8']
            }),
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }
    ]
  })
},
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      publicPath: 'img/',
      // publicPath : (css-file) ? '../img/' : img/, <--- ;p
      outputPath: 'img/'
    }
  },
    'image-webpack-loader'
  ]
},
```

if i use this code, i do not have any errors, but url's images in my `dist/css/style.css` file are `img/` whereas i want to have `../img/`

in SCSS :

```
background-image: url('../assets/image-test.png');
```

in EJS :

```
<img src="<%= require('../assets/image-test.png') %>">
```

Tree:

```
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.css  <-------(here i want ../img/)
│   │   └── style.css.map
│   ├── img
│   │   └── image-test.png
│   ├── index.html  <-------(here i want img/)
│   └── js
│       └── bundle.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── image-test.png
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── js
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── sass
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   │   └── variables.scss
│   └── views
│       └── index.ejs
├── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.prod.js
```

I use for this project:

```
"autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
"css-loader": "^0.28.9",
"ejs-loader": "^0.3.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
"file-loader": "^1.1.7",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
"image-webpack-loader": "^4.1.0",
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"style-loader": "^0.20.2",
"webpack": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
```

Comment: Can you describe more about your problem? Any errors? and How about the output when run webpack?

Comment: @TanDuong Yes sorry, if i use this code, i do not have any errors, but url's images in my `dist/css/style.css` file are `img/` whereas i want to have `../img/ `, however this should not change the url's template file

Comment: I tried with webpack 2 and it works. Can you provide version please?

Comment: @TanDuong "webpack": "^3.11.0"

Comment: @TanDuong, in production mode i want `../img/` in my CSS file and `img/` in my HTML, but currently it's either `../img` or `img/` I can not make the distinction

Comment: I have no idea for now.

Comment: Hi @eclaude  ,
I facing the same problem now. Did you get any solution for solving this problem

Comment: @ShifutHossain no sorry :p